# Aurelia and webpack during dotnet publish in ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, aurelia, asp-net-core-spa-services

The ASP.NET Core 2.0 project brings in Aurelia using

```
au new --here
```

I want to create the following artefacts when publishing the solution

```
\wwwroot\dist\app.bundle.js
\wwwroot\dist\vendor.bundle.js
```

I can achieve this by manually running

```
npx webpack --config webpack.netcore.config.js
```

But I would like to kickoff webpack builds when I publish:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

My ultimate aim is to have VSTS CI/CD process use MSBuild to automatically bundle the SPA files as required above.

Please note, during development I am already using hot module replacement via

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
```

And

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
    {
      HotModuleReplacement = true, 
      ConfigFile="webpack.netcore.config.js",
      HotModuleReplacementClientOptions = new Dictionary<string,string>{
        {"reload", "true"}
      }
    });
}
```

This works as expected. But now I need to achieve the same during publishing.

As a quick fix I've added a post-build event

```
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="npx webpack --config webpack.netcore.config.js" />
  </Target>
```

How do I get the custom MSBuild RunWebpack target explained [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/client-side/spa-services.md)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with an MSBuild target? Publish =/= build. I'd either put it in a `psake` build script or in a VSTS build task or somesuch..

Comment: To be clear, I'm not necessarily questioning or criticizing this choice, I'd genuinely like to know why specifically you want to do it this way (if it is a conscious choice) or if it doesn't matter. That information would make it easier for me to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

So I also ran into the same issue. I noticed that in the **webpack.config.js** file it had the following lines:

```
output: {
    path: outDir,
    publicPath: baseUrl,
    filename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js' : '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map' : '[name].[hash].bundle.map',
    chunkFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js' : '[name].[hash].chunk.js'
  },
```

But in the **webpack.netcore.config.js** file it had:

```
config.output.filename = '[name].bundle.js';
```

So when you publish it, it expects .net core to copy the app.bundle.js and vendor.bundle.js files but they aren't there, because webpack has it under a different file name due to caching purposes. 
So replace that line with the following:

```
config.output.filename = '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js';
```